# Basic R programming error

Tags: r

count1 should return the first position of 1 in the input. My code is not working. what is the mistake?

```
count1 <- function(x) {
    for(i in x) {
      if(i==1) break
    }
   i
}
count1(c(2,3,1,4))
[1] 1
count1(c(2,3,1,4,1,4,5,1))
[1] 1
```

I used same logic to write oddcount which counts the number of odd numbers. However, below code words but count1 does not

```
> oddcount <- function(x)  {
    k<-0
    for(i in x) {
    if(i%%2==1) k <- k+1
       }
    k
  }
> oddcount(c(1,3,4,5))
[1] 3
```

Comment: `?which` shall help you

Comment: `i` is the elements in `x`, not their indices.

Comment: @joel.wilson You beat me to it, the function using `which`:  `count1 < function(x) {
    which(x = x == 1, arr.ind = x)
}`

Comment: Try changing the function to `count1 <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    if(x[i]==1) break
  }
  i
}` but definitely you have better alternatives in R to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two functions are enough for the job:

```
# returning the 1st position of 1
which_1 <- function(x){
  which.max(x==1)
}

which_1(c(2,3,1,1,5))
[1] 3

# counting the number of odd nb
count_odd <- function(x){
  sum(x%%2 == 0)
}
count_odd(c(2,3,1,1,4))
[1] 2
```

Edit: Thanks David for pointing the typo!